# Vuejs Cannot Submit Form Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

I want to submit data via modal Semantic UI and Vuejs. But my form cannot submit data via Ajax. i'm tired to find the problem, maybe someone can help me.

My View like this.

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addProductCategory" class="ui form">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="description">
                <div class="field" v-bind:class="{'has-error': input.errorsAddProductCategory.name}">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input v-model="input.addProductCategory.name" type="text" id="name" name="name">
                    <div class="help-block" v-if="input.errorsAddProductCategory.name"
                         v-text="input.errorsAddProductCategory.name[0]"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui black deny button">
            No
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui positive right button">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    const URLS = {
        productCategory: {
            addProductCategory: '{{ route('product-category.store') }}',
        }
    };
</script>
```

Function to Add Data.

```
function addProductCategory() {
var data = app.input.addProductCategory;
data._token = CSRF_TOKEN;

$.ajax({
    url: URLS.productCategory.addProductCategory,
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        app.input.addProductCategory = {
            name: ""
        };
        app.input.errorsAddProductCategory = [];

        $('#modal-create').modal('hide');
    }
    error: function (data) {
        if (data.status === 401) { // unauthorized
            window.location.reload();
        } else if (data.status === 422) {
            app.input.errorsAddProductCategory = data.responseJSON;
        } else {
            alert('There is an error.');
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
}
```

And Vuejs

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: function () {
    return {
        input: {
            addProductCategory: {
                name: ""
            },
            errorsAddProductCategory: [],
            editProductCategory: {
                name: ""
            },
            errorsEditProductCategory: []
        }
    };
},
methods: {
    addProductCategory: addProductCategory,
}
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery to handle the request? Axios is an awesome http handler designed specifically for vuejs.

Comment: @Joe axios was not designed for Vue. It is a general purpose HTTP client. jQuery is acceptable for ajax in Vue.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @BertEvans don't have error. Just still on page and don't any responses..
But when i'm tring show alert, it's work..

Comment: Does the addProductCategory method get called? Does it call back to success or error?